# In automation testing how to Click on disabled element link In Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nodes, nightwatch.js

**Consider the following image:**
[image]

- **1.)** Disabled Element: the first arrow points to a **disabled** (inactive)  list element;
- **2.)** Problem: the second horizontal arrow is pointing towards the plus sign (`+`), which I want to click;
- **3.)** But the plus sign (`+`) is `disabled` as you can see in the browser console.

**Problem description:**

Firstly, I select the element in **inactive table** and then we will click on its **plus icon**.

**Code:**

```
var reactivate_categoryStatus = function() {
describe("", function() {
    it("reactivate category", function(browser) {
        variables.createdActivityCategoryName = 'testCategory_2017Apr19184658';
        browser.pause(2000);
        commands.checkAndPerform('click', browser, elements.adminRelationshipManagementPageElements.activityStatusInactiveLink);
        browser.pause(2000);
        browser.elements("xpath", elements.adminRelationshipManagementPageElements.activityStatusInactiveTable + "/tbody/tr", function(result) {
            var els = result.value;
            var count = 0;
            els.forEach(function() {
                count = count + 1;
                browser.getValue(elements.adminRelationshipManagementPageElements.activityStatusInactiveTable + "/tbody/tr[" + count + "]/td[1]/input", function(result) {
                    // console.log(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>Create name Of status activity "+variables.createdActivityCategoryStatusName);
                    if (result.value.includes(variables.createdActivityCategoryStatusName)) {
                        console.log('inactive name to reactivate : ' + result.value);
                        console.log(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>    if con status activity " + variables.createdActivityCategoryStatusName);
                        commands.checkAndPerform('click', browser, elements.adminRelationshipManagementPageElements.activityStatusInactiveTable + "/tbody/tr[" + count + "]/td[2]/span");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        browser.pause(2000);
    });
});
};
exports.reactivate_categoryStatus = reactivate_categoryStatus;
```